# Cannot POST to app_link_hosts. Permissions error

Tags: facebook

I am getting "permissions error" message when try to publish to app_link_hosts edge. Please advise me what am I doing wrong? I have checked Facebook permissions. I do have publish_actions permission and I can publish to user's wall no problem but cannot publish to app_link_hosts... Trying to set up a back link from a share link to my iOS app.

```
NSString *fbAccessToken = [[[FBSession activeSession] accessTokenData] accessToken];

NSString *theUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"myscheme://deeplink?playlist_id=%@",[postParams objectForKey:@"playlist_id"]];



NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                        @"MY APP NAME", @"name",
                        theUrl, @"al:iphone:url",
                        @"77948767", @"al:iphone:app_store_id",
                        @"MY APP NAME", @"al:iphone:app_name",
                        @"{\"should_fallback\": false}", @"web",
                        fbAccessToken, @"access_token",
                        nil
                        ];

/* make the API call */

[FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"/233246787764/app_link_hosts"
                             parameters:params
                             HTTPMethod:@"POST"
                      completionHandler:^(
                                          FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                          id result,
                                          NSError *error
                                          ) {
                          /* handle the result */
                          NSLog(@"Result = %@",result);
                          if(error) NSLog(@"error = %@",error);
                      }];
```